# Chrome Windows 10: Self signed certificate not working

Tags: google-chrome, ssl

I'm using Chrome 50.0.2661.87.

I develop locally and want to use self signed certificates (created with MAMP PRO 3.2.0).

I do the following steps:

- Go to the site (which points via hosts file to 127.0.0.1): E.g. https://www.my-local-dev-page.com
- Get an error: NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
- I click continue
- I click on the red lock in the top left corner inside the certificate popup I choose "export to file"
- I choose "DER-codiert-binär X.509 (.CER)"
- I click next and close chrome
- I import this CER file both via windows user certificates and also in the chrome settings in the ssl path of the root authorities
- I open up chrome and the error comes again

If I click again "continue", it seems that somehow it is working, but after a few requests, it is falling back and the error comes again.

What I would expect is that ALL requests in the future work without a problem and that a green lock is shown on the top left.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: One can't open https://www.tld.com because one makes redirection from HTTP to HTTPS (not from HTTPS to HTTP, like one do typically). One can open https://www.tld.com/contact for example and to see that you use certificate signed by CN = COMODO RSA Extended Validation Secure Server CA which is signed by CN = COMODO RSA Certification Authority as the root certificate. Thus SSL certificate, which you use on www.tld.com, is **not** self signed certificates. The site have some SSL problems, but no problems which you describes. One can't reproduce the described steps.

Comment: Sorry Oleg, you misunderstood the question. https://www.tld.com was just a dummy URL! I should better use https://www.my-local-dev-page.com. This website points via my hosts-file to 127.0.0.1. I edited my question!

Comment: I have on my local host 127.0.0.1 correct SSL certificate, which has no problems. I get it by [Let’s Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) for free. If you post some question where you describe instructions to reproduce the problem that you should make the description so that other can reproduce it.

Comment: How do you get a certificate for localhost?! You only can SSL certificates from Let's Encrypt for public domains...

Comment: I don't need to do this. I use public DNS name. If internal client connect to the server then the IP will be sent to the router which make IP NATing. Then the IP packet will be sent to the destination local sever because my local router know the public DNS name of my severer, but with local IP of the server. To be exactly the public IP address of my server is already the IP address of the router, which makes NATing. I think that more possibilities are possible.

Comment: That sounds interesting but seems to be a whole other topic. I simply want chrome in a current version to accept self signed certificates. Like Firefox does without problems.

Comment: I just answered on your previous question. OK, probably somebody else will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

The problem was, that the certificate was created with a wrong CN.

Now everything works as expected!